# Linearlayout not taking place over fragment

Tags: android, layout, fragment, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="ca.usherbrooke.whapl.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:elevation="4dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_pause"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_play"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/songname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and when I have a ListView in my `fragment_container`, the player with play/pause/next/rewind button is alway over the container, so I cannot access the last element in the list view, because it's behind my player (the linear layout after the fragment_container).

What should I change for the container only take the place he has and don't go under my player ?

By the way this layout is included in the layout of my main activity, wich is a DrawerLayout that contain my container + a NavigationView.

Comment: consider to warp it using LinearLayout or RelativeLayout to make it works. create Linearlayout and put your appbarlayout and framelayout inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `android:layout_marginBottom` property to the container equal to the height of the player.

Comment: That's what I've finally done but the player can have a different size, depending on the name of the song (a long title will use 2 lines)

Comment: So try to get the height of the player programmatically and on changes adjust the bottomMargin's property of the container.
Or you could use for the player the expandable BottomSheetBehavior from Design Support LIbrary.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at BottomSheetBehavior, sound good for what I want !